# Python program sending data via sockets, what OSI layers?

Tags: python, sockets, osi

In Python I have been playing around with server sockets that listen for messages, and client socket connections that send the data to the server.

Am i correct in thinking that the server/client python programs that utilize the socket module span layers 5 (session),6(presentation) and 7(application)? I think of the python code that utilizes sockets as presenting data, managing sessions and creating sockets using transport protocols such as tcp or udp.

Is my understanding/thinking correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Note that the OSI model is not commonly used in practice.  More typically, you see the Internet Reference model, which compresses the OSI layers 5, 6, and 7 into a single layer called the Application Layer.

Comment: Exactly. There are no OSI layers in a TCP/IP stack.